# How to retrieve data from two tables? Do I have to use join?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables, users and favourite songs.

The user registers to the site, and has to login. So the query for that is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$Name' AND Password='$Pass'
```

The favourite songs table also has their username in it. How do I change the query so that their favourite song is also selected? Once logged in, I want the song echoed back to them.

Song table:

```
Username  Song:
test1   | Singing in the rain
test2   | Nightdance
test3   | Firestorm
```

Users table:

```
Username  Password
test1   | 123123
test2   | 123123
test3   | 123123
```

Comment: Don't forget to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: This is a bad design to use the username as the user identifier. You should have an extra column named user_id, and use that to refer to users in all the tables. Your current design goes against the "good practice" that in a db, one information should be stored only once (in that case, the username). Regarding your question, I'm sure you'll get an answer within the next 5 min ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.Username, COALESCE(s.Song, 'Oh, you have no favorite song ?')
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN song s 
   ON s.UserName = u.UserName
WHERE Username='$Name' AND Password='$Pass'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the favorite songs table is named `favorite_songs_table`

```
SELECT u.*, f.song FROM users u
INNER JOIN favorite_songs_table f ON f.user_name = u.name
WHERE Username='$Name' AND Password='$Pass'
```